# Can't get Slide Out Tab on the right hand side of my page

Tags: javascript, css, positioning

I have a slide out tab, it works perfectly on the left, but when I change the settings to position it on the right - the tab image disappears and the content is stuck open.

Under the tab slide out DIV I have this js

```
$('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({

    tabHandle: '.handle',                     //class of the element that will be your tab
    pathToTabImage: 'images/getstarted.gif',  //path to the image for the tab *required*
    imageHeight: '139px',                     //height of tab image *required*
    imageWidth: '27px',                       //width of tab image *required*    
    tabLocation: 'right',                     //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
    speed: 300,                               //speed of animation
    action: 'click',                          //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
    topPos: '0px',                            //position from the top
    fixedPosition: false                      //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
});
```

Then there is a js file that has these settings

```
(function($){

    $.fn.tabSlideOut = function(callerSettings) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            tabHandle: '.handle',
            speed: 300, 
            action: 'click',
            tabLocation: 'left',
            topPos: '200px',
            leftPos: '20px',
            fixedPosition: false,
            positioning: 'absolute',
            pathToTabImage: null,
            imageHeight: null,
            imageWidth: null,
            onLoadSlideOut: false                   
        }, callerSettings||{});
```

MY CSS

```
.slide-out-div {

    padding: 12px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 87px;
    border: 2px inset #1e5e70;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #eefbfe;
    background-image: url(../images/stripe.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;  
    z-index:999;
}
```

My website is http://www.pagetree.co.uk

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do what you're asking in the 'correct' way. 
The correct way would be to set the slide-out (on your website the div called `float`) to `right: 0;` and tweak the actual javascript function (not the js you listed here, those are the function parameters). In those parameters you may have observed that there is no `rightPos:`, which means it can only be set from the left.

However, if you can give the `float` div a width, you could manage to position it to the right edge of the screen, in percents. In that case, you would give the float div these properties `width: 20%; left: 80%;`. **DISADVANTAGE:** Your div's width will vary in proportion to the screen size.

That's for the positioning. And still then it will not work because your js calculates the tab to slide out from the left. I'm guessing you got this plugin here: http://www.building58.com/examples/tabSlideOut.html . It's does the job, but it's not very extensible.

**CONCLUSION:**
You need to write your own javascript for a function like this.
**HOWEVER, why use javascript when you could do it with a CSS:hover selector?**

Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TvGQ5/, it achieves exactly what you want (if you really want on click and not on hover, toy around with the `:target` selector.

If you use this solution, don't forget to set the parent element (on your website the div called `middle` to `overflow-x: hidden;`. Also, on all your pages it works, but on your homepage you need to move the floated div to the middle div, not the body.

Comment: THANK YOU that is incredibly helpful! One question, your css version uses css3 right? So would that have limited browser compatibility? Thanks again for your time! @Tyblitz

Comment: Yes it uses CSS3 'immediate child' selectors (>); I was too lazy to create classes (you could do it with CSS2 and classes as well). The only browser still in use with a considerable market share, that doesn't support CSS3 is IE8. Check here for browser-support on web-related stuff: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) . Compatible solution up to IE7 if you use classes instead of CSS3 selectors. Css-transitions are not supported until IE9, but the slideout will work correctly (only no smooth transition). Ultimately it depends on your audience (under 50 => drop IE7- support)

Comment: Thank you so much! Absolutely brilliant. Can I just ask one more question! I wanted to move the slide out tab to the right because on an iPad it is hidden behind the content slider, and I could not locate the problem whatsoever. It works perfectly on a computer. I assumed I must have some issue with my z-index. @tyblitz

Comment: Yes that's a z-index issue. You have to set `#float {z-index: 50;}` and `#rotmenu {z-index: 5;}` (it's currently set to 9999).

Comment: @KieranVyas Yes it does. I am a 100% certain. I tested it on your website (with Google Web Inspector) and did exactly this on your homepage and it worked. I just retested it and it works. Something's wrong at your end. We're drifting away from the original question though. This question should be closed/ accepted