# sliding panel on right-hand side, like existing one at top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have existing HTML/CSS/JavaScript that works fine for a "click to open" sliding panel from the top of the page, like this:

```
<div id="machineSelectorContainer">
    <div id="machineSelectorTray">
        <table id="machineSelector">
            <tr id="machineSelectorThumbnailTextRow">
                <td class="machineSelectorThumbnailText">VM1</td>
                <td class="machineSelectorThumbnailText">VM2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="machineSelectorThumbnailPicture">
                    <img src="images/placeholderThumbnail.png" />
                </td>
                <td class="machineSelectorThumbnailPicture">
                    <img src="images/placeholderThumbnail.png" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="machineSelectorThumb">
        <div id="machineSelectorThumbText">
            &bull;&bull;&bull;
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with

```
*, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#machineSelectorContainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: -120px;
}

#machineSelectorThumb {
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 120px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: lightblue;
    -ms-opacity: 0.4;
    opacity: 0.4;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 100;
}

#machineSelectorTray {
    position: absolute;
    height: 120px;
    z-index: 100;
    margin: auto;
    left: 50%;
}

#machineSelector {
    background-color: lightblue;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 8pt;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 120px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#machineSelector > table {
    height: auto;
}

#machineSelectorThumbnailTextRow {
    height: auto;
}

.machineSelectorThumbnailPicture > img {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: auto;
}

.machineSelectorThumbnailText {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

and

```
$("#machineSelectorThumb").click(function () {
    var element = $("#machineSelectorContainer");
    var currentTop = element.offset().top;
    var newTop = -(currentTop + 120);
    element.animate({
        top: newTop
    }, 200, function () {

    });
});
```

(I put a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/mikebaz/rtTe5/1/ but note that the styling does **not** work correctly there for some reason - it's not worth messing with it as it's close enough, but be aware the thumb button doesn't overlap the tab in a normal browser setup.)

This works exactly how I want.  I would like to have the same kind of behavior and design for a panel that slides out from the right, with the open button vertically centered and rotated, sliding open from off the right side of the window into view (right to left slide).

I have found a lot of different answers around pieces of this, such as [CSS- hide element off the right of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746649/css-hide-element-off-the-right-of-the-screen) to get the off-screen positioning, and I looked at [Can't get Slide Out Tab on the right hand side of my page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967674/cant-get-slide-out-tab-on-the-right-hand-side-of-my-page) but that uses an image for the rotated text, which I don't want to do (among other differences).  It seems that the script would be similar, but I'm stuck on how to build the CSS properly.  I can't seem to get the combination of rotation, off-screen portion, and dynamic height working.  In particular, I can't seem to get the contents to show or the thumb text to properly center in the thumb button.  Here is what I have right now that is getting there:

```
<div id="machineControlsOuterContainer">
    <div id="machineControlsContainer">
        <div id="machineControlsTray">
            <table id="machineControls">
                <tr>
                    <td class="machineButton">Button</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Button</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Button</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Button</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Button</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="machineControlsThumb">
            <div id="machineControlsRotatedContainer">
                <div id="machineControlsThumbText">&bull;&bull;&bull;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
#machineControlsOuterContainer {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#machineControlsContainer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 150px;
    right: -120px;
}

#machineControlsThumb {
    width: 30px;
    height: 60px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: lightblue;
    -ms-opacity: 0.25;
    opacity: 0.25;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 50%;
}

#machineControlsRotatedContainer {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#machineControlsTray {
    position: absolute;
    right: -120px;
    height: 100%;
}

#machineControlsThumbText {
}

#machineControls {
    background-color: lightblue;
    -ms-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 120px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.machineButton {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

with the script:

```
$("#machineControlsThumb").click(function () {
    var element = $("#machineControlsContainer");
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var currentLeft = element.offset().left;
    var currentRight = -150 + (windowWidth - currentLeft);
    var newRight = -(currentRight + 120);
    element.animate({
        right: newRight
    }, 200, function () {

    });
});
```

I can tell I'm close, but I just can't finish closing the loop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I finally figured this out.  I had to do a little bit more manipulation of different pieces, and add some vertical centering script (I can't get the CSS to cooperate).

CSS:

```
#machineControlsOuterContainer {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#machineControlsContainer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 150px;
    right: -120px;
}

#machineControlsThumb {
    width: 30px;
    height: 60px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: lightblue;
    -ms-opacity: 0.4;
    opacity: 0.4;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}

#machineControlsRotatedContainer {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#machineControlsTray {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: auto;
}

#machineControlsThumbText {
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}

#machineControls {
    background-color: lightblue;
    -ms-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 120px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    text-align: left;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

#machineControls td {
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
```

Adjustment script:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    verticallyCenterElement("machineControlsThumb");
    verticallyCenterElement("machineControlsTray");
});
verticallyCenterElement("machineControlsThumb");
verticallyCenterElement("machineControlsTray");

function verticallyCenterElement(elementName) {
    var element = $("#" + elementName);
    var height = element.height();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var newTop = (windowHeight - height) / 2;
    element.css("top", newTop);
}
```